# What is the equation of circle when two lines are tangent

Tags: geometry

What is equation of circle when two lines y=x and y=x-4 are tangent to a circle at (2,2) and (4,0) respectively.

Comment: Did you start skeching the lines and circle?

Answer (score 1):

You can just plug values into the general equation of a circle and differentiate it to find where the tangents are.
$$(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=r^2$$
$$2(x-a)dx+2(y-b)dy=0$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{x-a}{y-b}$$
Then just plug in values for $x$ and $y$ to evaluate $a$ and $b$. Then the rest becomes quite simple.

Answer (score 1):

The tangent lines are parallel, so that simplifies a lot. The points $(2,2)$ and $(4,0)$ are therefore diametrically opposite, so the centre is halfway between them, ie, $(3,1)$.

Radius of circle is distance between $(2,2)$ and $(3,1)$ (centre) that is $\sqrt{2}$.

Thus the equation is

$$(x-3)^2 + (y-1)^2 = 2$$